# Date-fns format distance is not in correct words

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am facing a problem with the UI and want to show the timestamp distance into `3 hours ago` and `4 hours ago` etc. The timestamp coming from the server with a property named `createdAt` which has the following value.

```
createdAt: "2021-10-27T05:24:37.642Z"
```

To solve this problem I am using library like [date-fns v2.25.0](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started) builtin function [formatDistance](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/formatDistance).

```
import { formatDistance} from 'date-fns';

const timestamp = createdAt ? new Date(createdAt) : '';
console.log(formatDistance(Date.now(), timestamp, {addSuffix: true}));
```

But it is giving back the distance in the following words

```
in about 3 hours
in about 4 hours
```

instead of

```
3 hours ago
4 hours ago
```

What I am doing wrong? If you know any other good library please you can share.

Comment: Reverse the two arguments in `formatDistance`

Comment: if using moment package `moment('2021-10-27T05:24:37.642Z').fromNow();`

Comment: @Evert Thanks now it working. You can create an answer based on your comment. So I accept that.

Comment: To calculate "n days ago" or "n weeks ago" try date-fns [intlFormatDistance](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/intlFormatDistance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the arguments:

```
console.log(formatDistance(timestamp, Date.now(), {addSuffix: true}));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use any other popular package such as [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment), which I do believe have more custom configuration, but if you want to use this package, instead of having to change the `formatDistance` function, it would be easier to change the result string like:

```js
import { formatDistance } from "date-fns";

const createdAt = "2020-08-27T08:24:37.642Z";
const timestamp = createdAt ? new Date(createdAt) : "";
const distance = formatDistance(Date.now(), timestamp, {addSuffix: true });

console.log(distance.substring(distance.indexOf(distance.match(/\d+/g))));

// => 2 hours ago
```

Comment: Don't suggest moment for new code. It's being phased out. The issue OP has simply that the arguments are reversed.

Comment: Not even moment themself recommend using it. From their github:  "Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library."